# R | ggplot2 | bar in barplot does not start at the right value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I want to visualize the reference ranges of several liver enzymes (for example GOT and GPT) that I calculated with two programs "kosmic" and "RLE" using ggplot2.

I do not understand why the bars always start at 0, even if the lower range is for example 16.02.

How do I need to change my code so the minimum and maximum values of the bars look like that:

[16.02,45.46] [9.16,60.52] [16.10,68.90] and [9.30,64.40].

Thank you in advance!

```js
#install.packages("ggplot2")

library(ggplot2)


program <- c(rep("kosmic",4),rep("RLE",4))

value <- c(16.02,45.46,9.16,60.52,16.1,48.9,9.3,64.4)


parameter <- c(rep("GOT",2),rep("GPT",2),rep("GOT",2),rep("GPT",2))

table1 <- data.frame(program,value,parameter)


p <- ggplot(table1, aes(parameter,value, fill = program))+
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
        

print(p)
```

[image]

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: You have two observations for each program-parameter combination and it's stacking them. How would you like it to look?

Comment: like this: https://imgur.com/a/eq2Le34

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
table1 %>%
  group_by(parameter, program) %>%
  summarize(min = min(value), 
            median = median(value),
            max = max(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
ggplot(aes(interaction(parameter,program), fill = program))+
  geom_tile(aes(y = median, height = max-min), width = 0.6)
```

[image]

Edit:
Okay this is hacky, but:

```
table1 %>%

 # example of reordering the parameters
 mutate(parameter = fct_relevel(parameter, "GPT", after = 0)) %>%
  # forcats offers a variety of fct_*** functions to change factors
  # (factors are a data type that can separately store labels and ordering)

  group_by(parameter, program) %>%
  summarize(min = min(value), 
            median = median(value),
            mean = mean(value),
            max = max(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  ggplot(aes(parameter, mean, color = program))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.3), size = 10,
                width = 0) + 

  # control the legend so the key squares aren't gigantic to match the error bar widths
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=8))) +

  # example of assigning different colors. 
  # a variety of scale_color_* functions are available
  scale_color_manual(values = c("kosmic" = "#cc5588", "RLE" = "#779988"))
```

A downside of this is that the width/spacing of the bars will vary depending on your graphic output aspect ratio, so to use it might take some fiddling to get as you want.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I think OP is looking for this. Upvoted!

Comment: thank you, but I am looking for something like this:

https://imgur.com/a/eq2Le34

Comment: Hmm. I don't know an obvious way to do that in ggplot2, since the geom_bar/geom_col geoms are constructed to have a zero baseline, but geom_tile and geom_rect don't to my knowledge have the same handy dodging syntax. So I think you'd need to fake it, eg by making transparent geom_cols below the ones you want, or by coercing the spacing for geom_tile/rect.

Comment: Thank U Jon! Not all heroes wear capes

Comment: how can I manually change the colours of the bars? and how to I change the sequence of the parameters? Because now they string together in alphabetic order.

Comment: Edited with example of reordering axis (typically easiest by converting that variable to a "factor", which can be sorted in whatever order you want) and changing colors of bars.

Comment: [BTW, happy to help. the expectation on this forum is to keep questions "self-contained" to the extent possible, and to search for answers first. if you search SO for "[r] [ggplot2] reorder x axis" and "[r] [ggplot2] change color of bars" you should find a wide variety of quality answers that should help if you have further questions.]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried to write the script by my own, but my r-programming skills were unfortunately not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want, I'd suggest a box plot instead of a bar plot:

```
ggplot(table1, aes(x = parameter, y = value, fill = program, color = program)) +
    geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()) + 
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, color = 'black')
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but Jon posted exactly what i was looking for